# Selector de ficheros con filtro por extensión

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Estoy intentando que al presionar un botón en una aplicación de Android, se abra el gestor de ficheros predeterminado que tenga el usuario en su dispositivo, y le permita eligir un fichero.

Pretendo que sólo se muestren aquellos ficheros que tengan una extensión específica, por ejemplo, "*.ejemplo".

Lo único que he logrado encontrar en la documentación de Android es que se pueden filtrar los resultados del gestor en base a sus "mime-types".

Por ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
```

En este fragmento de código, en el setType() puedo especificar un mime-type para filtrar. Por ejemplo, si escribo image/bmp me mostraría todos los .bmp de su sistema de ficheros, o si escribo image/* mostraría cualquier tipo de imagen.

El caso es que la extensión que deseo filtrar es inventada, no tiene mime-type asociado, y si escribo "*/*" me muestra TODOS los tipos de ficheros, incluyendo los que no serían compatibles.

¿Cómo podría hacer que sólo se muestren los ficheros que tengan la extensión que yo decida (es decir, la extensión que mi aplicación soporta)?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Intenta asignando en el metodo setType el MIME type asi: `intent.setType("application/miextension");` y dime si te funciona.

Comment: No funciona :(

Si pongo application/ejemplo, los ficheros con la extensión .ejemplo no coinciden con ese criterio, y creo que es porque al ser una extensión sin asociación, su mime type es nulo.